# Getting StackOverflowException in WebService (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-overflow, asmx, windbg

I have a WebService named ECService.asmx, which contain 230+ WebMethods.
When I separate those methods into several "asmx" or comment out half of the code, the StackOverflowException won't happen anymore.

According to MSDN:

> A StackOverflowException exception is thrown when the execution stack overflows by having too many nested method calls.

I am pretty sure that I don't have any recursive methods.
All they do is return a dataset upon calling, and that's all.

So I did some researchs and convinced to use whatever tool to extract a full userdump of the process (iisexpress), then use windbg tool to inspect the stack tree logged in it. I tried capturing a full userdump by using Visual Studio 2017's option "Debug> Save Dump As...":

```
kbn
.loadby sos clr
!CLRStack
```

then I got this

```
0:033> !CLRStack
OS Thread Id: 0x584 (33)
Child SP       IP Call Site
06b625a8 77a21d3c [FaultingExceptionFrame: 06b625a8] 
06b9ef00 77a21d3c [InlinedCallFrame: 06b9ef00] 
06b9f540 77a21d3c [InlinedCallFrame: 06b9f540] 
06b9f53c 65cce181 DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
06b9f540 65c7b892 [InlinedCallFrame: 06b9f540] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)
06b9f574 65c7b892 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
06b9f578 65c7b39f [InlinedCallFrame: 06b9f578] 
06b9f670 65c7b39f System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)
06b9f748 05aeeb10 [ContextTransitionFrame: 06b9f748]
```

yet I found barely anything related to StackOverflowException. To be honest, I already don't know what to do beyond this point...

I also tried using Debug Diagnostic Tool to capture a full dump, but the rule "Crash rule for all IIS/COM+ related processes" I set up has never been triggered. Did I do it wrong? I would like to provide more information if I miss anything.

(Pardon me that I may cannot include the full file due to business sensitiveness. <strike>Now I am intern in a business company, the manager asked me that I cannot ignore this issue by using any mechanic workarounds.</strike>)

research reference:

[exception code: 0xc00000fd. Debugging a StackOverflowException](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/debug-stack-overflow-exception/)

[Using windbg to solve problems](https://blog.miniasp.com/post/2008/05/18/Use-WinDbg-Analysis-and-Solve-Program-Hang-Problem.aspx)

Comment: tt's been a while since I used SOS but CLRStack will only dump the current thread. Try !EEStack -EE and see what that gives you - it will dump stack traces for all threads and you should be able to see which method has got wrapped around itself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension

Comment: `analyze -v` sets the thread context on the offending thread. From there you can use !CLRStack.

Comment: @AdamBenson `!EEStack -EE` does dump all threads like you said, but I failed to recognize the problematic thread. The reference you offered is helpful, and thanks for quick comment!
@LievenKeersmaekers. It says `FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke` [full result](https://pastebin.com/BjXkEPcg) So I guess I shall start investigate from here, don't I? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a .NET stack overflow crash dump available right now, but here's my memory:

The `!threads` command should list the .NET threads. If there was an exception on a thread, that thread should have an indicator in the "Exception" column. Switch to that thread with `~<number>s`, then use `!clrstack`.

It should also work from native side, since .NET exceptions are also normal SEH exceptions. If you use the navtive threads command `~`, there should be one thread marked with `#`, which indicates a thread with an exception. If you can't see one, then it's likely the active thread, because the active thread indicator `.` overrides the exception indicator. In any case, you should be able to switch to the thread with the exception using `~#s` (literally, not replacing # by a number).

Whether the stack space is really exhausted, should be possible to figure out using the `!teb` command and looking at the stack base and stack limit. Then compare that to the stack pointer (ESP regiser).

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I have managed to print the stack trace of the thread. [(Screenshot)](http://i.imgur.com/ZeWNEWY.png) However, the term you mentioned like "ESP register" is quite alien to me. I haven't learnt assembly language or similar stuff like that. Anyway, I accept this as the best answer, though I still cannot figure out the real cause behind it.